# Finding thresholds to maximize TPR with an ensemble of classifiers while satisfying FPR constraint

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, classification, ensemble-learning

I have two classifiers that each gives me the probability that some input is `bad` (higher scores mean input is more likely to be `bad`).

I have scored lists of 100 known `good` and 100 known `bad` inputs against these classifiers. For simplicity let's just say my results are this:

```
>>> good_results = np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=0.6, size=(100,2))
array([[0.02475983, 0.02674755],
       [0.28967236, 0.26380374],
       [0.0755475 , 0.42218259],
       ...

>>> bad_results = np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=1.0, size=(100,2))
array([[0.73440053, 0.91102782],
       [0.80983753, 0.99047158],
       [0.66919376, 0.94840667],
```

Given classifier thresholds `thresholds = [t_1, t_2]`, an input will be considered `bad` if *either* of its scores is above the respective classifier threshold, i.e.:

```
input_scores = [0.2, 0.7]
is_bad_input = any([input_scores[i] >= t for i, t in enumerate(thresholds)])
```

Using the above results and final scoring function, I want to find the classifier thresholds that maximize the True Positive Rate while keeping the False Positive Rate at or below 2%.

**What I've tried**

My approach so far has been to sweep across possible threshold values and calculate the TPR and FPR, then plot a ROC curve, and choose classifier thresholds that satisfy FPR <= 2%.

**What I would like**

However, it feels like I should be able to solve this problem more formally, perhaps using something like a solver library.

In practice, I have ~20 classifiers and ~200k known `good` and `bad` results for this calibration, so I need a solution that scales.